# Should I be using more than one viewmodel for a database table?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Bit of confusion, which I'm sure can easily be cleared up :).

Lets say we have a table called "Contacts". The "Index" view for this table would be a datatable, listing all contacts in the table with First name, email and phone. Now, this would have a viewmodel containing Firstname, email and phone.

Next we would need a details page, which will have the details for each contact in full, IE, fullname, first or second contacts, other phone numbers, website address and notes etc. Should this be a second Viewmodel?

Then we'd have a create page, which had have all the fields to be filled in. Would this be another viewmodel?

Finally, would this all go into the same class file or separate files?

Thanks

Comment: That's why ViewModel's where invented. Feel free to Create 3 different ViewModels. It's less confusing when You have ViewModels which contains only Required information than having a Model and leaving most of fields as nulls.

Comment: and for those things i suggest to keep it in one file.

Comment: I thought as much :). And what about keeping them in the same file or separate files? If the same files, what would the layout of said file be as an example?

Comment: @SouthWilts I wouldn't recommend keeping them in one file, perhaps a **folder**.

Comment: Let's say it's a Table with name User. So You could Create a file with name of UserViewModels and put all ViewModels there. But I guess there is no correct answer for this part of question. Depends on You. Some prefer to separate files some prefer to keep it in one.

Comment: When you are faced with a question like one file or many files, just think, what if it scales up and you get more and more details. Then you can see one file would be a disaster. Also it sucks if you're searching for a class and you don't see it in the solution explorer.

Comment: Here is a nice article about datamode, viewmodel etc. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2006/07/23/676272.aspx

Comment: I'd say that why to use viewmodel is just because it provides a convenient way to work with entities from db and i cannot see why not making as many viewmodels as you want to. I'd create vm for any complex page that uses data from database.Let's say you want to display employees so you create EmployeeVM viewmodel, then you may want to display some information from Employees,Departments and Organizations - you make another viewmodel EmpDepOrgs you do not usually pass three models to your view because it makes no sense and potentially allows access to your db or server logic from client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual the answer is ain't common, it depends on how you really want to implement it. But for the sake of patterns and organized code, i would recommend that you have:

- Separate Viewmodel per view: each viewmodel should only contain as
  many data as many you want to display/work with on the given view.
- For the sake of [Separation of concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and unit testability: one class - one file, and one
  class per task the class is concerned for. So the given class is only required to change for one reason only.

Comment: I disagree with 'one class - one file'. This ViewModels correspond to the same object but sometimes it is beiing cut a bit. For those situations I think it's better to keep it in one file

Comment: @MajkeloDev: as written in my answer, its really a matter of how developer wants to implement it. Structuring your codebase is really like a matter of taste of mouth. However in the longer run, I find it more logical that i don't have to search for a file by examining files contents whose contains more than one class, just need to look up the filename which contains one class only, named like the class's name.

Comment: I've decided to create a folder for each "section" as it were, IE, Contacts is a section, Users is a section, Inventory is a section. Then "ContactsIndexViewModel", "ContactsEditViewModel" etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

So you can have Model and multiple ViewModels.It is best to keep every ViewModel in a different file. If you use same Models as your ViewModels, your application should be very small and simple and should contain only CRUD operations. But if you are building large or enterprise applications with large teams (with two or probably more developers), you should have concepts like Dependency Injection, Services, Repositories, Façades, Units of Work, Data Access Objects etc.

To simplify your mapping needs between Models and ViewModels, you can use AutoMapper https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

or install with nuget Install-Package AutoMapper

Comment: We intend to use AutoMapper, but we first want to be comfortable with hand coding it :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: Yes, it seems logical in your specific case. View/edit models often differ, too - in datatypes, sets of data included, fields editable vs. viewable. On the other hand, with modern browser-based frontends less specialized view models may lead to looser coupling between backend API and frontend, making UI changes easier.

Code organization is a subjective matter.

Comment: Thanks for that, would accept as answer but Kayess gave a bit more information. Still appreciated though!

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a more than one view model for a view. First you should create a models for your database tables(contact, contact details, etc..). Later based on your view requirement you can create a view model using models. Even model can be directly used as a view model if requires.

Better to create a separate view model for a view. it is useful to combine a data from multiple models and also you can have a calculated properties and methods.